# Automatically checking out TFS changes from one machine to another

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, protractor, getlatest

I'm writing Protractor/Jasmine E2E tests on a local machine in Visual Studio 2015 which has my project stored through TFS and then I am running those tests each night on another machine.  I may be misunderstanding the concept here and/or missing the point of the appropriate tool for this situation.

But, is there a way such that when I check in changes on my local machine that those changes are automatically checked out (get latest) on the secondary machine without having to manually get latest on the files?

Comment: You can use a scheduled build in TFS to download the files and run the build. Or include "tf vc get /version:T" in the script to run the tests to download the latest files from your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deploy a build agent on the second machine, when you queue build, build agent will get latest version of your project into the source directory.

Or as @jessehouwing mentioned in comment, you can use [TF.exe command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) in a script on your second machine to get latest version of your project:

```
tf get /version:T
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I would just note that if anyone uses this in the future, just double check that the path to TF.exe is mapped into your system variables.